# How come there's no standard way to submit a web form with the keyboard?

Tags: forms, accessibility, web, keyboard, standards

I know that in general you can hit Enter while focused on a form field to submit a form. However certain elements like selects and textareas break this behavior. How come we don't have a web standard that permits the user to submit a form with the keyboard regardless of the type of element that's currently focused? (tabbing to the Submit button is not a reasonable general solution, it takes too much attention and time)

Incidentally, I noticed some sites (e.g. Asana, Gmail, GitHub) introduced Ctrl-Enter to reliably submit with the keyboard. Is there any effort to standardize this behavior in browsers through an RFC? This seems like a glaring hole in web forms.

Comment: You had me at "How come we don't have *a* web standard"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for "Submit form"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/keyboard-shortcut-for-submit-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usability of Ctrl + Enter Submitting of Forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/usability-of-ctrl-enter-submitting-of-forms)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a glaring hole in web forms, it's just that web forms follow the UX of computer forms. <kbd>Enter</kbd> is, from the [Windows Keyboard Shortcut guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_windows_shortcut_keys), to:

> Carry out the default command of the dialog box or command of the selected control.

You essentially want to have an extra control for the specific case when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the command of the selected control.

From what I am aware of there has never been a convention to 'submit a form regardless of the input'.

Where as having a shortcut for when you might have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> 10+ times is worth it, typically you won't have forms with 10 dropdowns in a row.

The times when I have seen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a shortcut is typically when you have a text area, e.g. when sending an email. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is used as a shortcut is many instances e.g. in the address bar for Firefox Ctrl + Enter will convert `example` into `www.example.com` and go to the page, so it's definitely not a standard.

From what I can tell, the annoyance that you have isn't annoying enough to have a standard for it.

Comment: Windows made the standard for Windows forms. If it is good enough for 90% of the world, why not simply apply it to the Web as well? Are web forms somehow that different from a user standpoint that we cannot decide to use Enter to submit the form? How is the web different from Windows, in such a way that this is impossible?

Comment: @nocomprende I think you're agreeing with me, but not sure?

Comment: Your last sentence dismisses this as a problem, yet Windows thought it was enough of a problem to solve it. Since apps are moving from Windows to the web, shouldn't we keep the learning and improvements and solutions hard-won over decades? When billions of people are annoyed, even a tiny bit, the improvement of fixing a tiny thing is significant. But, it was already eliminated, so why does App 2.0 have that bug again? Are humans smart enough to learn from past mistakes, or not? If not, well, let's get on with the real work of butting our heads against walls instead of shooting the breeze here!

Comment: @nocomprende They didn't solve it in Windows. As far as I know the experience in Windows is exactly the same as on the web. If you're on a dropdown, enter will close the dropdown not submit the form. This is the case in both Windows and web forms.

Comment: Dropdowns are neat, but they have usability problems.

Comment: Why is Windows relevant? How come sites like Asana, GitHub, and Gmail are using a de facto standard Ctrl-Enter, but the web community hasn't attempted to develop a real standard?

Comment: @GabeKopley Three sites is a very bold claim to be 'de facto'. See the [linked question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/usability-of-ctrl-enter-submitting-of-forms) for people who don't believe that Ctrl+Enter is any kind of standard.

Comment: @GabeKopley Windows (+ Mac OS as well) matter because they defined most of the UX rules that are used. The web is an extension of the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply @icc97 . I realize these things are very tricky, but am hopeful that we can improve upon the status quo.

Comment: @GabeKopley a problem with that is that UX often *is* the status quo. The simplest rule of UX is that you use what people are familiar with as they already have a mental model of how it works.

Comment: I agree! That's why I don't use Ctrl-Enter - it's messy to override defaults.

Comment: Windows apps often "solved" the problem by using -- often form-specific -- shortcut keys `Ctrl-S` to activate a `Save` button. The problem is there was no universal "submit this form" keystroke, and in the world of the web, many Ctrl-key combos will be swallowed by the browser (or annoy users if they expect the browser to react instead of the page).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is some users (bank cashiers for example) using keyboard only (for speed sake). When selecting an option from a select box, they need to press Enter to choose the selection. If the form would submit on Enter, this could cause to an error if Enter is accidentally pressed twice.

There are implementations, like onChange -> submit, but this is useful (not always) when your form only contains one element which is select.

Comment: I think the question is why isn't there some other key or key combination that would **always** result in the form submitting.

Comment: In this case I am flagging this as duplicate

Comment: Please do not flag as duplicate. I am seeking _why_ there's not a web standard for submitting a form with the keyboard not _how_ to submit a form with the keyboard.

Comment: @GabeKopley, sorry but it looks like you are looking for upvotes rather than the answer. Your question is similar to "why are there still diesel cars"..

Comment: No, it is more like: "Why are all cars not electric"? They have existed for 100 years, and if they are better, why aren't we standardizing on them? If a standard way to submit a form would be better, why have we not gone with it yet? But this is similar to "why are humans human". Because... oh nevermind

Comment: @nocomprende, exactly my point..

Answer (score 0):

I think just nobody has taken the initiative to propose a standard. I'll do so here: Ctrl-Enter should be the standard and browser vendors should build it in.

Comment: Downvoters, please say why this is unfavorable. My thinking is if Google found it useful in Gmail, and the community thought a universal keyboard-based form submission method would be helpful, Google would add it to Chrome, and other browsers would follow. I'd love to know why this is a bad idea so that I can give up on my effort to shed light on this issue. Thanks!

For example, are you concerned with breaking backwards-compatibility? Do you believe this is not useful-enough functionality to get its own key combo? Or some other reason you are against it?